# Kill command won't work correctly in bash script

Tags: bash

I was running an ubuntu console, when I type the following command, all the processes would be perfectly killed.

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep 'job1/' | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2}')
```

But when I was trying to use crontab to call a script routinely, things went wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$(ps -ef | grep 'job1/' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
echo $pid
kill -9 $pid
# the following commands were never executed
sleep 5
/data/job1/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh
```

The result was just like this:

```
15432 15438
Killed
```

It seems to just killed the job, but won't execute the following commands. Any idea?

Comment: Did you kill the script itself by accident?

Comment: Ah, exactly!!! Thank you sooooooo much! You really save my day!!:)

Comment: you should consider using `pgrep` or `pkill`

Comment: Note that killing with a `KILL` signal should be considered the very last resort; read this for explanation - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make a script that `kill`s things by PID then you need to be very careful that you kill the right things.

You already have `grep -v grep` to avoid killing the grep itself, but it seems that you have not put in anything to protect against the script killing itself. Since you know your own PID you could `grep -v` that, but what if you are 123 and one of the things you want to kill is 1234? Probably safer to go by script name.